# Error loading MpFilter.sys

Tags: windows-7

How can I fix "`Error loading MpFilter.sys`"? Do I need to format my netbook?

I tried to remove some newly installed software and hardware, but the problem still occurs.
This is the problem of my netbook:
MpFilter.sys
PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGE_AREA
If this is the first time you've seen this stop error screen, restart your computer. if this screen appears again, follow these steps:
check to make sure any new hardware or software is properly installed.
if problem continue, disable or remove any newly installed hardware or software. Disable BIOS memory options such as caching or shadowing.

Technical  information:
*** STOP:0x00000050
*** MpFilter.sys  Address FFFFF880013BC78 base at FFFFFF88001B000.

I do the instruction above but the problem is still.
Please help me. Thank You.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. As it stands, there isn't enough information to answer your question. Can you edit it to include more info to help people diagnose and solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

`MpFilter.sys` belongs to the AntiVirus tool from Microsoft. Try to [install the latest version 4.8.0204.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=5201) and look if it fixes your issue.